# How to Display a custom value like customer number in order Email

Tags: magento-1.9

I am working on a solution for the task to display a customer number in the order confirmation email.
There is already a custom attribute customer_number which is displayed in the register form and the customers back-end.
It seems to get displayed by calling a helper.

This is how it is displayed in the register form:

```php
<input type="number" 
    name="<?php echo Company_Helper_Data :: CUSTOMER_NUMBER_FIELD ?>" 
    id="<?php echo Company_Helper_Data :: CUSTOMER_NUMBER_FIELD . "id" ?>" 
    value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getData( Company_Helper_Data :: CUSTOMER_NUMBER_FIELD ) ) ?>" 
    title="<?php echo $this->__('Customer Number') ?>" class="input-text" />
```

This is how it gets called in the customer back-end

```php
<input type="text" 
    name="customer_number" 
    id="customer_number"
    value="<?php echo $this->getCustomer()->getCustomerNumber() ?>" 
    title="<?php echo $this->__(' Customer Number') ?>" 
    class="input-text" />
```

So I simply tried to put this code into the order/default.phmtl:

```php
<?php echo $this->getCustomer()->getCustomerNumber()?>
```

Which does not work. The Order cannot be set.

I am rookie to programming. Does anyone has an idea how to call the customer-data in the order email-template and display it in the order confirmation?

Answer (score 0):

For this in Magento, you'll have to go in magento backend admin panel,
next go to

> system=>Transactional Emails

Here you'll find your email template.
After this open the email template and then place this where you would like

> {{ var customer_number }}